# Reading a text file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
readFromFile = open('C:\\Users\\sunka\\Desktop\\exampleFile.txt','r')
readFromFile.readlines()
print(readFromFile)
```

After running the code, I am getting the following issue

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\sunka\\Desktop\\exampleFile.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

it's not printing the contents in the file.

Kindly help me to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try the following :

```
readFromFile = open('C:\\Users\\sunka\\exampleFile.txt','r')
fh = readFromFile.read()
print(fh)
```

It prints out all the lines in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Your `readFromFile` variable is a file object, that you can read data from.
The `readlines` function returns array of lines inside that opened file.

So what you want to do is:

```
with open('C:\Users\sunka\Desktop\exampleFile.txt','r') as file_obj:
    print(file_obj.readlines())
```

Take a closer look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) next time.

Comment: You can read any file the same way. The difference would be in how will you treat the contents.